# Relation between OM and Sri Yantra

Tags: tantra, om

Namaskar to all saintly ladies and gentlemen,
I'd like to know the evidence sloka about relation between OM and Sri Yantra.
Recently I read an interesting article that OM sound creates Sri Yantra by tonoscope.
Please someone give me torch of wisdom.

Comment: Take any Internet source with a pinch of salt.

Comment: *Recently I read an interesting article that OM sound creates Sri Yantra by tonoscope.* Can you provide the link?

Comment: Thanks for your concern . Here is the URL: https://todoestarelacionado.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/cimatica-dando-vida-a-la-materia-con-el-sonido-hans-jenny-1968/